# How to force a chatbox DIV to stay displaying the bottom as new messages appear with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for a project of mine I basically need a chatbox to stay scrolled at the bottom. I've attempted examples I've found on here but none of them seem to work. Here is my code (simplified with most appearance stuff removed):

HTML

```
<div class="chatbox" id="chatbox-outer">
         <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox-inner">
        <p class="chat0" id="personchat0">Example text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#chatbox-outer {
height: 400px;
width: 330px;
position: fixed;
}

#chatbox-inner {
height: 300px;
width: 330px;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
}
```

The entire chatbox dialogue is scripted, made to come in as the user clicks a button:

jQuery:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
        $('#button1').hide();
        $('#playericon1').fadeIn();
        $("#chat1-0").fadeIn(function(){
        $('#personicon1').fadeIn();    
        $("#personchat0").fadeIn(function(){
        $("#button2").fadeIn(); 
        });
        });    
    });
```

But the issue is, they just get pushed downwards and the user needs to manually scroll to keep up with the chat which is less than ideal. What line of jQuery/code and CSS changes do I need to add to force it to stay at the bottom and make new messages essentially push the other upwards?

[image of the chatbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyaBh.png)

I'm a huge beginner so I understand I likely haven't coded in the best or most efficient way but what I need is a solution that makes this code here work.

Thank you, help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight`

```js
var inner = document.getElementById('chatbox-inner');

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'foo';
  inner.appendChild(div);
  inner.scrollTop = inner.scrollHeight;
},500);
```

```css
#chatbox-outer {
height: 400px;
width: 330px;
position: fixed;
}

#chatbox-inner {
height: 300px;
width: 330px;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox" id="chatbox-outer">
  <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This definitely the type of scrolling I'm after, and this is almost perfect! Is there any way to get specific divs to appear (like how I did so in my script) instead of your 'foo'?

Comment: @Anajinn that's beyond the scope of your original question. I didn't reference your code because it references code that isn't in your post. You  just want to set `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight` whenever you add or show elements in it and you want it to stay scrolled to the bottom. All you need to do is define `inner` and then use `inner.scrollTop = inner.scrollHeight` when you want it to stay scrolled to the bottom.